# How to add list object to dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following response model

```
public class GetMediaTypesReponse
{
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> Mediatypes { get; set; }
}
```

and the following business logic

```
public async Task<GetMediaTypesReponse> GetMediaTypes()
{
    GetMediaTypesReponse response = new GetMediaTypesReponse();
    response.Mediatypes = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    IList<Media> medias = await mediaRepository.GetAllAsync();

    foreach ()
    {

    }

    return await Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

```
  public class Media
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid MediaId { get; set; } // Using GUID as this table might have historical data without removing of records
        public int MediaTypeId { get; set; } // for future Use like Banner image
        public string ThumbnailImg { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsHeroImage { get; set; } //Will be displaced first
        public string ImageText { get; set; } //Text to find images
        public string ImageFileName { get; set; } //Uploaded image filename

    }
```

I need to Create one dictionary object in for each loop 
 And then  add that to list object Because we don't need to pass parameters to dictionary object constructor There we don't have the chance to pass
    parameters in the constructor.

Comment: please post your `Mediatypes` class as well

Comment: Your `foreach` loop will never execute, because you are instantiating  `response.Mediatypes` just before it. foreach will iterate only if it contains any data.

Comment: hariharan Mediatypes  is dictinary object of model class

Comment: @HariHaran, OP posted type of `Mediatypes` in first code block of question

Comment: Prasad telkkikar ok may i know to to add list result to dictionary above

Comment: What data do you want to add into the dictionary?

Comment: @Sweeper  IList<Media> medias result.

Comment: So I'm assuming you know how to convert a `Media` to `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: `foreach(var m in medias){
response.Mediatypes.Add(m.Prop1.ToString(),m.Prop2.ToString()) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , you could try the following method :

```
public async Task<GetMediaTypesReponse> GetMediaTypes()
    {
        GetMediaTypesReponse response = new GetMediaTypesReponse();
        response.Mediatypes = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        IList<Media> medias = await mediaRepository.GetAllAsync();

        foreach (var media in medias)
        {
            var item = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var property in media.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                item.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(media).ToString());
            }
            response.Mediatypes.Add(item);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(response);
    }
```

Comment: Chen almost my requirement above u specified is right? but I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  from item.add after iteration from loop

Comment: What is the definition of your `Media` ?

Comment: Media is an DB entity ..i mention above in question section can u see once now

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the result of the response you want, and what the string in ` Dictionary <string,string>` represents?